# T-SQL working out a running total using a figure from another table as a starting point

Tags: sql

I have tried to search for the answer to this but I think the fact I'm using another table as the starting point is throwing me off, any help is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to work out how much stock I can supply for each sales order based on a first come first serve basis. The CTEs are to establish the stock starting point, in the example below the free to sell starting point is a quantity of 233 pieces.

The result I am looking for is [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bis66.png). Returning zero once the all the stock has been allocated.

```
WITH INV AS (

            SELECT 
              PCSID
              ,WarehouseID
              ,SUM(StockQty) AS Stock
            FROM Inventory
            GROUP BY
              PCSID
              ,WarehouseID
),

ORDERS AS (
            SELECT 
              PCSID
              ,WarehouseID
              ,SUM(QtyBOTotal) AS OrderQty
            FROM SalesOrders
            WHERE OrderBookByMonth <> 'Backorder'
            GROUP BY 
              PCSID
              ,WarehouseID 
),

FTS AS (--Free to sell
            SELECT
              INV.PCSID
              ,INV.WarehouseID
              ,CASE WHEN Stock - OrderQty < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Stock - OrderQty END AS FreeToSell
            FROM INV
              LEFT JOIN ORDERS ON ORDERS.PCSID = INV.PCSID  
                                        AND ORDERS.WarehouseID = INV.WarehouseID
)

SELECT 
  S.PCSID
  ,S.SONumber
  ,S.DateOrdered
  ,S.OutstandingQty
  ,FTS.FreeToSell
  ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.PCSID ORDER BY S.DateOrdered) = 1 THEN  
    MIN(FTS.FreeToSell) - S.OutstandingQty  
    ELSE 0 END AS Balance  
FROM SalesOrders AS S  
LEFT JOIN FTS ON FTS.PCSID = S.PCSID
                    AND FTS.WarehouseID = S.WarehouseID
 WHERE OrderBookByMonth = 'Backorder'
    AND PCSID = 874331
GROUP BY 
    P.Product_Code
    ,P.PCSID
    ,S.SONumber
    ,S.DateOrdered
    ,S.OutstandingQty
    ,FTS.FreeToSell 
    ,S.OutstandingQty
```

My result based on the above

```
PCSID   SONumber    DateOrdered OutstandingQty  FreeToSell  Balance
874331  SO-1249122  2021-08-23  14.000000        233.000000  219.000000
874331  SO-1287785  2021-09-14  283.000000       233.000000  0.000000
874331  SO-1275080  2022-03-07  1.000000         233.000000  0.000000
874331  SO-1286812  2022-06-23  1.000000         233.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Please provide all data on `PCSID=874331`. Otherwise, can't help you find issue.

Comment: The PCSID is just an identifier for the product, the help I need is working out the remaining stock quantity for the next line.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure what the connection is between the SQL script you've written and your intended outcome.

Comment: Oh, the script I have written is my attempt to solve the issue. I don't need the FreeToSell column or the balance, I was just using that to visualise. I am getting stuck when using the free to sell figure in a window function.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay I figured it out.

,FTS.FreeToSell - SUM(S.OutstandingQty) OVER(PARTITION BY P.PCSID ORDER BY S.DateOrdered ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Qty

as a new CTE RUNNINGSTOCK

Then
SELECT
RUNNINGSTOCK.*
,CASE WHEN RUNNINGSTOCK.Qty > OutstandingQty THEN OutstandingQty
WHEN RUNNINGSTOCK.Qty < 0 THEN CASE WHEN OutstandingQty + Qty < 0 THEN 0 ELSE OutstandingQty + Qty END END

Comment: Your answer could be improved by putting the code into code block formats. It would be easier to read.